# Is link trading a recommended method of SEO?

Tags: seo, links

I've read in some places that link trading is a good way to get in-bound links, but read in other places that link trading is punished by search engines.

Should I use link trading or is it counter-productive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the links are from bad sites, then this will bring your site down. For small businesses particularly, cross linking is definitely a good technique, as you are likely to want to genuinely endorse each other.

Bought links are bad – don't pay a site to link to you, and if the site has millions of links, it won't count for much.

Comment: also try to make sure that there is a relevance to your business activities. i.e. don't cross link with a website that sells dipers if you have a website that sells car parts. ( unless it's about racing parts and you provide dipers for those shitting their pants )

Comment: Crosslinking isn't good for SEO

Answer (score 3):

> The sites that link to you can provide
>   context about the subject matter of
>   your site, and can indicate its
>   quality and popularity. However, some
>   webmasters engage in link exchange
>   schemes and build partner pages
>   exclusively for the sake of
>   cross-linking, disregarding the
>   quality of the links, the sources, and
>   the long-term impact it will have on
>   their sites. This is in violation of
>   Google's Webmaster Guidelines and can
>   negatively impact your site's ranking
>   in search results.

[Link Schemes at Google Webmaster Central](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66356)

To see why this practice has, at best, a net zero effect for both linking sites (assuming that the normalized number of outbound links are equal between the sites) and, at worst, a net negative effect for one - or *both* - of the sites (assuming that the normalized number of outbound links on Site A is far greater than that of Site B, such that the value of Site B's link to Site A is greater than that of Site A's link to Site B; *both* sites may be adversely impacted if reciprocal linking adds to the damping factor on each site's ranking) take a look at Wikipedia's [PageRank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank#Simplified_algorithm) entry.

The simplified algorithm presented at Wikipedia does not factor in any damping or additional factors considered by Google when determining the page's rank - it's still relevant in this case, however, as it illustrates the reasoning behind Google's discouragement of reciprocal linking schemes.

Answer (score 2):

Generally (indiscriminate) link trading is frowned upon by SEs and often you will gain little benefit and may probably even face a penalty.

However, inbound links from worthy sites; sites in good standing, and ideally sites with complementary content can help a lot. I've no idea what are of business you are in, but contacting specific sites offering complimentary products and services and arranging a reciprocal link exchange might be useful, but simply registering with generic link farm will not.

There are plenty of others ways of getting inbound links - writing articles about your area of business and submitting them to news/trade magazine-type sites, or offering a free resource (information/service/download) are classic approaches.

But ultimately, you will only get decent inbound links if you have good/interesting/sought-after content, products or services - and you can't short-cut the issue through link farms.